# ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "TwigExtension" from the global namespace

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, twig, twig-extension

I'm trying to create a Twig Extension using the service container, but i'm getting a "ClassNotFoundException".

Here the exception:

> ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "TwigExtension" from
>   the global namespace in
>   \path\to\symfony-simple-blog\src\YagoQuinoy\SimpleBlogBundle\Twig\BlogExtension.php
>   line 11. Did you forget a use statement for this class? Perhaps you
>   need to add a use statement for one of the following:
>   Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\DependencyInjection\TwigExtension

Here the code:

Twig extension:

```
namespace YagoQuinoy\SimpleBlogBundle\Twig;

/**
 * Description of BlogExtension
 *
 * @author yagoquinoy@gmail.com
 */
class BlogExtension extends \TwigExtension
{

    public function getFilters() {
        return array(new \Twig_SimpleFilter('timeAgo', array($this, 'timeAgoFilter')));
    }

    public function timeAgoFilter() {

        return 'yolo!';
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'blog_extension';
    }
}
```

service.yml

```
services:
    yago_quinoy_simple_blog.twig.blog_extension:
        class: YagoQuinoy\SimpleBlogBundle\Twig\BlogExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Edit: Solved.

> [smarber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1507546/smarber)
>   Twig_Extension not TwigExtension,
>   symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: `Twig_Extension` not `TwigExtension`, http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: Works like charm! A needle in a haystack... Why there is two classes that the only difference is a "_"...

Answer (score 0):

You can still update to Symfony 4.4 by fixing your twig version in your composer.json by running

```
composer require twig/twig ~2.0
```