# Symfony2 + Twig: Attempted to call function "replace" from the global namespace

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.6, symfony-2.7

I'm getting this error in my app and I can't find where I'm failing:

> **Attempted to call function "replace" from the global namespace.**

This is the Stacktrace:

```
[1] Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException: Attempted to call function "replace" from the global namespace.
    at n/a
        in /var/www/html/reptooln_admin/app/cache/dev/twig/eb/76/c3cb3f071f775598b83974700b4a2523941a76b0f3cf8801d01d9210eae0.php line 318
```

Now at my code I have this Twig Extension defined:

```
services:
    app.twig.extension:
        class: AppBundle\Extension\AppTwigExtension
        tags:
            -  { name: twig.extension }
```

And this is the class:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Extension;

class AppTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            'var_dump'   => new \Twig_Filter_Function('var_dump'),
            'empty' => new \Twig_Filter_Function('empty', array($this, 'is_empty')),
            'isset' => new \Twig_Filter_Function('isset', array($this, 'is_set')),
            'isnull' => new \Twig_Filter_Function('isnull', array($this, 'is_null')),
            'ucfirst' => new \Twig_Filter_Function('ucfirst', array($this, 'uc_first')),
            'ucwords' => new \Twig_Filter_Function('ucwords', array($this, 'uc_words')),
            'count' => new \Twig_Filter_Function('count', array($this, 'co_unt')),
            'sizeof' => new \Twig_Filter_Function('sizeof', array($this, 'size_of')),
            'concat' => new \Twig_Filter_Function('concat', array($this, 'concat')),
            'in_array' => new \Twig_Filter_Function('in_array', array($this, 'inarray')),
            'array' => new \Twig_Filter_Function('array', array($this, 'array_')),
            'add_to_array' => new \Twig_Filter_Function('add_to_array', array($this, 'add_to_array')),
            'replace' => new \Twig_Filter_Function('replace', array($this, 'replace')),
            'htmlentitydecode' => new \Twig_Filter_Function('htmlentitydecode', array($this, 'htmlentitydecode')),
        );
    }

    public function replace($subject, $search, $replace)
    {
        return str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
    }
    // functions goes here

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_twig_extension';
    }
}
```

What is wrong? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985614/classnotfoundexception-attempted-to-load-class-twigextension-from-the-global) post but doesn't help in my case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error, it seems you've registered a filter called `replace`, but you're trying to call it as a function.

So this should already work (but I don't think this is what you want to do):

```
{{ my_variable|replace('something', 'with', 'this') }}
```

What I think you're trying to do is:

```
{{ replace(my_variable, 'replace', 'this') }}
```

To register a function, add a method called `getFunctions` to your `AppTwigExtension` class, and move the `replace` definition to that. See [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#id2) for more details.